# What's the difference between observing in a given direction and operating in that same direction?

Tags: quantum-gate, measurement

So starting with an *up* particle:
$$
\lvert \uparrow \rangle =  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
My understanding is that you can measure $\lvert \uparrow \rangle$ in $X$ and have a 50% chance of getting $\lvert \leftarrow \rangle$ and a 50% chance of getting $\lvert \rightarrow \rangle$ where:
$$
\lvert \rightarrow \rangle =  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
    \end{bmatrix}
\text{ and }
\lvert \leftarrow \rangle =  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
    \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
but you could also *operate* in $X$ which would be the equivalent of passing it though a `NOT` gate:
$$
X \cdot \lvert \uparrow \rangle =  
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    1 \\
\end{bmatrix} = \lvert \downarrow \rangle
$$

I've read that measuring qubit spin is more or less equivalent to measuring the orientation of a photon which can be done by passing it through polarized filters. If the photon is measured to be in one orientation and then is measured in a different orientation it has a certain probability of *snapping* to be in that other direction.

So in this example, that would be equivalent to measuring an *up* qubit in $X$. But how does *operating* in $X$ come into the equation? I understand the mathematical effect it has, but what does this mean for the physical qubit? Is it also being passed through a filter and how is that different from measuring?

Thanks!

Comment: you can rotate spin using magnetic field; I don't remember how exactly to do it, but it should be explained in good QM courses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, "*operating on a state with an observable*" does not have direct physical meaning (i.e. you cannot think of it as evolving the state doing something to it).

What does have physical meaning, is applying a *unitary* operation to a state. Every unitary operator corresponds to a physical operation that you can (in principle) implement, transforming (reversibly) states into other states according to some rule.

In the particular case of $X$, you *can* actually think of it as an evolution, because $X$ is *both* Hermitian (thus an observable) and unitary (thus an evolution). What this evolution means physically depends on the implementation. If you are dealing with the polarisation of a photon, it can be representing the action of a phase shifter, which rotates the polarisation.

But it's important to distinguish between "*acting on a state with the evolution $X$*" and "*measuring the state with the observable $X$*". To "measure $X$" means physically to apply a measurement which makes the state collapse into one of the eigenstates of $X$. This involves doing something like acting on the state with a Hadamard gate and then measuring in the computational basis, so you can see how this is rather different than evolving with $X$.